# MongoDB schema to identify common concepts?

Tags: mongodb, schema

Coming from some dgraph/GraphQL background, totally new to MongoDB. I did read MongoDB schema documentation yet can't figure out it's applications.

Can I use schema to achieve the following functionality:

I insert documents of varying structure, nesting levels. Two examples:

first document:

```json
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Deere",
  "dob": "1960-07-14"
}
```

second document:

```json
{
  "incident": "call",
  "time: "2023-05-12T12:20:00Z",
  "partner" : {
      "first_name": "Frank",
      "last_name": "Drabin",
      "dob": "1980-03-14"
  }
}
```

Now can mongodb help me to find these two "persons" in that I define a person as a schema having a {"first_name", "last_name" and a "dob"}?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say _find these two persons_? What information do you have when querying the system? Are those the only two ways that a person will show up in a document and you don't know which of them you're looking for?

Comment: No, I don't know the documents which get inserted. Essentially I want to achieve if any Json object has a first_name, second_name and dob at any nesting level whatsoever, it's a 'person', irrespective of any other fields.

Answer (score -1):

> Yes, MongoDB can help you find the two "persons" based on the schema you've defined. MongoDB provides a flexible querying mechanism that allows you to search for documents based on specific criteria.

```
**db.collection.find({
    "first_name": { $exists: true },
     "last_name": { $exists: true },
     "dob": { $exists: true }
    })**
```

Comment: Please help to explain the downvote. Is the answer factually wrong or not good practice?